# Title: React useContext Hook not Updating Components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a React application and utilizing the useContext hook to manage global state across multiple components. However, I've encountered an issue where the components are not updating when the context value changes.

I have set up the context and provided it at the top level of my component tree. The context itself seems to be updating correctly, as I can see the changes in the console logs. However, my components that consume this context through useContext don't re-render with the updated values.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// MyContext.js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext();

const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('initialValue');

  const updateValue = () => {
    // Simulating a change in context value
    setValue('updatedValue');
  };

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ value, updateValue }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { MyContext, MyContextProvider };
```

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { MyContextProvider } from './MyContext';
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';

function App() {
  return (
    <MyContextProvider>
      <ComponentA />
    </MyContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// ComponentA.js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './MyContext';

const ComponentA = () => {
  const { value, updateValue } = useContext(MyContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
      <button onClick={updateValue}>Update Value</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;
```

I expect that when I click the "Update Value" button in ComponentA, the context value should be updated, and the component should re-render with the new value. However, this is not happening. The value in the ComponentA remains the same, even though the context value has changed.

Am I missing something in the useContext hook usage or the way I'm providing the context? Any guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It is working and updating the value in my computer.